# How to take a subslice of an Arc<[T]>

Tags: rust

```
fn subslice(a: Arc<[T]>, begin: usize, end: usize) -> Arc<[T]> {
    Arc::new(a[begin..end])
}
```

The above "obvious implementation" of the subslicing operation for `Arc<[T]>` does not work because `a[begin..end]` has type `[T]`, which is unsized. `Arc<T>` has the curious property that the type itself does not require `T: Sized`, but the constructor `Arc::new` does, so I'm at a loss for how to construct this subslice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

To explain why, let's look at what `Arc` actually is under the covers.

```
pub struct Arc<T: ?Sized> {
    ptr: Shared<ArcInner<T>>,
}
```

`Shared<T>` is an internal wrapper type that essentially amounts to "`*const T`, but can't be zero"; so it's basically a `&T` without a lifetime.  This means that you can't adjust the slice at this level; if you did, you'd end up trying to point to an `ArcInner` that doesn't exist.  Thus, if this is possible, it must involve some manipulation of the `ArcInner`.

`ArcInner<T>` is defined as follows:

```
struct ArcInner<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: atomic::AtomicUsize,
    weak: atomic::AtomicUsize,
    data: T,
}
```

`strong` and `weak` are just the number of strong and weak handles to this allocation respectively.  `data` is the actual contents of the allocation, stored inline.  And *that's the problem.*

In order for your code to work as you want, `Arc` would not only have to refer to `data` by another pointer (rather than storing it inline), but it would also have to store the reference counts and data in different places, so that you could take a slice of the data, but retain the same reference counts.

So you can't do what you're asking.

---

One thing you can do *instead* is to store the slicing information *alongside* the `Arc`.  The [`owning_ref`](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref) crate has [an example that does exactly this](http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/index.html#atomic-reference-counted-slices-that-share-ownership-of-the-backing-storage).

Comment: What is wrong with this reasoning: Suppose I have an `Arc` pointing to `[1,2,3]` with a reference count 1. I make a clone and dereference to make reference count 2, then slice to make a reference to `[2,3]`, and finally wrap it up with an `Arc::new`. The `Arc` for `[2,3]` will have reference count 1, even though there is another reference to the data from `[1,2,3]`, but the backing array can't be dropped until both refs are lost. If the `Arc` for `[2,3]` is dropped, this will cause the rc for `[1,2,3]` to drop back to 1, allowing the backing array to be dropped after losing the first ref.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro That's just not how pointers *work*.  For that to be possible, you'd have to have both `Arc`s pointing to the same `ArcInner` (so they share the reference count), whilst having different `data` fields.  It's fundamentally impossible.  The reference counts and the data being stored are *one and the same*.  The only way for this to work is to do what `owning_ref` does: store *both* the ref-counted data itself *and* the subset of that data you're interested in.

Comment: This might be a confusion on my part, but I thought that a `[T]` was a pair of pointers to the start and end of the array, or something like that. So the slices corresponding to `[1,2,3]` and `[2,3]` would not be the same data, but would be pointing to the same data. The `Arc`s would keep these pointers instead of the data itself. Or are you saying that they are holding the whole array next to the reference counts? (P.S.: I think I will use `owning_ref` since it seems that they have solved my exact problem.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro No, `[T]` *is* the data.  Think about it like this: `&[T]` is comprised of a pointer to the first element and the number of elements.  `[T]` is what that pointer is pointing at.  `ArcInner` contains the *actual* data, right there.  That's what I meant when I said it was being stored inline.

Comment: Ooohh... now it makes more sense why `Arc::new` can't work here, since the length of the slice isn't even stored in the struct. Thanks!